# Why does Google Cloud Run instance show wrong available memory and number of cores

Tags: google-cloud-run

When I let my application output the available memory and number of cores on a Google Cloud Run instance using linux commands like "free -h", "lscpu" and "top" I always get the information that there are 2 GB of available memory and 2 cores, although I specified other capacities in my deployment. No matter, I set 1 GB, 2 GB and 4 GB of memory and 1, 2 or 4 CPUs the mentioned linux tools always show the same capacity.

Am I misunderstanding these tools or the Google Cloud Run concept, or is there something not working like it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Run services run container on a non standard runtime environmen (named BORG internally at Google Cloud). It's possible that the low level info values are not relevants.

In addition, Cloud Run services run in a sandbox (gVisor) and system calls can be also filtered like that.

*What did you look at with these test?*

I performed tests to validate the multi-cpus capacity of Cloud Run and [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-performances-with-multiple-cpus-a4c2fccb5192) about that. The multi cpu capacity is real!! Have a look on it.